# Asynchronous UDP Server for multiple clients in C#

Tags: c#, .net, sockets, network-programming, udp

I have a task to do and I am new to networking, so like to discuss before coding down. I have to write down server side UDP application. Server listens for connection request from many clients (could be 100 or more). When it receives it then it does some handshake, by sending acknowledge back and forth couple of times, with the client application to know its identity. When connection is established it receives different types of data from the clients which it does processing and put in the sql database and send acknowledge back to client. Periodically send command to clients for specific information it requires.

I am using C# with Visual Studio 2005. Should I use multi threading? threadpool? Asynchronous or sync UDP Server?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: i m doing same thing can you please tell me ..whats the right solution for that.?

Answer (score 1):

Are you sure what you want is a UDP server? Terms such as "connections", "handshakes" are all TCP related.

Comment: Thanks for your concern Lex. Sorry for bit confusion. My real question is should I follow multithreaded approach to deal with multiple clients (could be 100) and most of them will send data same time. Most of the example I saw on internet is multithreaded TCP server, means a single thread for a connection. What about UDP Server?  With handshake I meant server and client will some exchange encrypted data for identity purpose to be sure it is right client and server.

Comment: I use the same approach (similar as TCP one) in my UDP server for #SNMP, http://sharpsnmplib.codeplex.com/SourceControl/changeset/view/03d2e03be043#SharpSnmpLib%2fMessaging%2fListenerBinding.cs It seems to work fine. Of course there are other UDP server approaches existing.

Answer (score 0):

I would use asynchronous methods in both the server and the client. It will complicate things, especially in the client.

The reason is that you write that the server will send stuff to the client sometimes. This makes a simple request/reply type of communication impossible (the client calls `Send` and then uses `Receive` until a proper answer have been received).

If you can scrap that requirement I would use synchronous clients (do some polling instead) which would make stuff a lot easier for you to understand.

If you have .Net 3.5, why don't you create a WCF service instead? It supports TCP and callbacks (server can call stuff in the client).

Comment: Thanks jgauffin. Well I do not have to write down for client as it is already implemented in hardware. My UDP clients are machines. I only need to write about UDP server that will grab data sent by UDP clients, send them response and send them commands for a task. So wodnering should I follow multi threading or I simple create a socket and when data is received it goes to callback and process the data. But wondering would this be efficient when around 100 clients send data same time.

Comment: I would create an asynchronous server. Callbacks + BeginReceive/EndReceive is asynchronous programming.